# Plex Media Server and Plex Home Theater

Tags: macos, plex, h.265

I have Plex Media Server on a Mac Pro serving video to Plex Home Theater on a Mac Mini.
All file formats play just fine except for HEVC h.265 files.

I always get the "Please Wait" message for a couple of seconds when starting the file or when trying to skip back or forward. The timecodes are messed up and the progress bar does not accurately reflect the true position of the play head. The file will play fine if I just let it play through but the skipping back and forth creates a problem.

I am trying to figure this out and wonder if anyone else has had this issue.

Comment: I have almost the exact same setup (Mac Pro running Plex Server serving to various computers, iOS devices). Almost all of my media is encoded as h265, and I have not had this problem. Are you on the newest version of server? Are you using the web client? What is your network speed (between the MP and the Mac Mini)?

Comment: The server and client are up to date. No updates available. I am using Plex Home Theater on the Mac Mini. The Mac Pro is an older 2006 MP and is running Lion 10.7.5. My local network is all Gigabit equipment. All the h264, MP4, mpeg,ts,etc content plays fine. Just the h265 that I have a problem with.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with Plex, since if I transfer the file and play it with VLC, it plays just fine. Comforting to know it is possible to play these files with a similar Mac setup just fine.

Comment: Have you tried contacting Plex support or filing a bug report? They should be able to help you get to the bottom of this

Comment: Thanks NoahL I posted on their forums also. I may submit a ticket if I don't get any response.